# Jetbrains Teamcity Build Agent: как ограничить число потоков?

Tags: teamcity

На моём рабочем компьютере установлен Jetbrains Teamcity Build Agent и он периодически делает сборки нашего продукта. Во время сборки процессор оказывается загружен на 100% и компьютер жутко тормозит так, что становится невозможно работать.

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли как-то ограничить количество потоков сборки или снизить приоритет процесса сборки?